# How to make flutter audioplayer more consistent

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app which uses a Metronome object to trigger an audioplayer to play a sound. Unfortunately, each time the sound is played there is some random delay, around 0-100ms. The Metronome callback also changes the colour of an Icon on the app, which seems to be very stable, so I don't think it's the Metronome which is inconsistent (I also used some logs which are saved within the Metronome callback to see how deterministic it is, and it seems to be within
a few ms). So I rather think the audio jitter is coming from the audioplayer.

I have wrapped the audioplayer in a Singleton class like this:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class Audio {
  static final AudioCache playerCache = AudioCache();
  static AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);

  static void init(String file) async {
    playerCache.load(
      file,
    );
  }

  static void play(String file) async {
    audioPlayer = await playerCache.play(
      file,
    );
  }
}
```

In the code my app runs `Audio.init('click.mp3');`, and the Metronome callback triggers `Audio.play('click.mp3');` (this is also where I changed the Icon colour and saved logs when that was enabled for debugging).

So far I've tried adding the `mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY` to the `playerCache.play`, however this results in no sound being played at all. I've also tried using both Metronome.epoch and Metronome.periodic, however this makes no difference, and like I said, the Metronome triggers seem to be very consistent (within +/- 5ms if the logs and visual feedback are to be believed).

Also to note, the jitter is worse on the Android emulator, but is still very much present on a real device (built with the `--release` option).

Am I expecting too much determinism for this AudioPlayers  package? Is 100ms jitter the best it can do? Is there any other way to structure the code for more consistent playback? Or do I need to figure out a "lower level" (i.e. Java/Kotlin/Swift) implementation?

Many thanks in advance for any input :)

Comment: The `audioplayers` package is based on the abandoned `audioplayer` which are both somewhat antiquated methods of playing audio in Flutter. I suggest you use a newer audio plugin such as `just_audio` and see if it performs more consistently.

Comment: @Abion47 `just_audio` is much better thanks. It's still not 100% reliable but definitely better. I could only get it to work by triggering both the `player.setAsset()` and `player.play()` in the metronome callback, but I'm wondering if there's some way I can "cache" the asset on startup (i.e. run something like `setAsset` on startup, so only the `play` command is in the callback) to possibly improve performance. Any ideas? I also tried various combinations of `await` before the setAsset and play commands, but it didn't seem to make much difference

Comment: @Robert Did you find a solution for this ? I'm exactly in the same situation. I get jitter +/- 50 ms with just_audio which is clearly audible.